# GAEの部分的なファイル差し替え

Tags: google-app-engine

GAE/goにてサーバー開発を行っておりますが、アプリ側(Go側)担当者とUI側担当者がおり
UI側担当者がサーバーのhtml/cssや画像ファイル等の静的のみ差し替えたい場合があります。

現在はgoapp delpoyにてアプリ全体をdeployして差し替えているのですが、
UI側担当者のファイル差し替え頻度の方が圧倒的に多いので、
アプリ全体をdeployせず、一部静的ファイルのみ差し替えたいのですが可能でしょうか？

Comment: 質問の回答にはなっていませんが、もしアプリ全体に影響を与えず静的なファイルのみdeploy出来ればよいのならば、serviceをアプリと静的リソース用に分割して、dispatch.yamlを記述することで、静的リソースのみdeployさせることも出来ます。 参照: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/an-overview-of-app-engine
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/dispatchref

Comment: 部分deployが出来ないとなると、ご教示頂いた内容が目的のこととなりました。(「承認」をしたいので恐れ入りますが、解答欄に同内容記載いただけますでしょうか。)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

代替案になりますが、もしアプリ全体に影響を与えず静的なファイルのみdeploy出来ればよいのならば、serv‌​iceをアプリと静的リソース用に分割して‌​、dispatch.yamlを記述するこ‌​とで、静的リソースのみdeployさせる‌​ことも出来ます。

参照: 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/an-overview-of-app-engine
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/dispatchref

Answer (score 0):

AppEngineはデプロイされているファイルの、一部を差し替えることはできません。

頻繁にデプロイしたい場合は、手動でやるのは大変なので、CIを利用してデプロイを自動化することで、ファイル差し替え時の作業を減らすことができます。
http://qiita.com/koki_cheese/items/ee25795bcd85ef72889c